# How can I fill between edges of these characters in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

here is my image

[image: a.jpg]

if I use imfill function,I get like this image

[image: b.jpg]

I need to put the hole in number 6.
how can I do this

plz can anyone help me

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following solution:

I played with filling image and filling negative of image, until solving it.

Here is my code:

```
I = imread('https://i.imgur.com/Ap2PX2E.png');
I = im2bw(I);

J1 = imfill(I, 'holes');
J2 = imfill(I, [1, 1]);
J3 = imfill(~J2, [1, 1]);
J4 = imfill(~J3, 'holes');
J5 = J1 & (~J4);

figure;imshow(J5)
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more simple and robust approach than provided by [Rotem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42589016/7649907):

```
I = imread('https://i.imgur.com/Ap2PX2E.png');
I = im2bw(I);

I2 = imfill(I,'holes');         % Create filled image
I3 = I & imerode(I2, ones(3));  % Create enclosed hole boundaries
I4 = I2 & ~imfill(I3, 'holes');  % Subtract enclosed holes

figure;
imshow(I4)
```

[image: Result]