# How to fill only the internal section of a shell with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm writing a script to process .png images similar to how 3D printing slicers work.
I need to fill the inside of the objects 'shell' but not gaps in the shell itself.

First I tried using MATLAB `imfill` function which gets me 90% of the way but runs into trouble if there's a internal wall or gap, in that case it fills the shell and the gap as well. (image 2).

I then tried a set of if statements that fill based on encountering walls moving along the image, filling after every other wall encountered. This works except for when it encounters a wall that doesn't have a void after it like a long side wall, (image 3).

My desired result is in image 4. That was done with a manual `imfill` but the image sets I want to process are in the thousands so an automated method is nearly essential.

```
%method 1
solid = imfill(im);

%method 2
% im aware this code is bad and full of redundant checks and conditions
% it was written as a fast check to see if what i believed the failure would 
% be was correct which it sadly was. I'm not as interested in the content
% (I can fix that myself) as I am the general outcome. 
slick = imread('image.png');
solid_im = zeros(size(slick));
for kx=1:x
        last=0;
        is_filling = 0;
        for ky =1:y
            if slick(kx,ky) == 1 && last == 0 && is_filling == 0
                solid_im(kx,ky) = 1;
                last = 1;
                is_filling = 1;
            elseif slick(kx,ky) == 1 && last == 1 && is_filling == 0
                solid_im(kx,ky) = 1;
            elseif slick(kx,ky) == 0 && last == 1 && is_filling == 0
                solid_im(kx,ky) = 0;
                last = 0;
            elseif slick(kx,ky) == 0 && last == 0 && is_filling ==0
                solid_im(kx,ky) = 0;
            elseif slick(kx,ky) == 1 && last == 0 && is_filling == 1
                solid_im(kx,ky)= 1;
                last = 1;
                is_filling = 0;
            elseif slick(kx,ky) == 1 && last == 1 && is_filling == 1
                solid_im(kx,ky) = 1;
            elseif slick(kx,ky) == 0 && last == 1 && is_filling == 1
                solid_im(kx,ky) = 1;
                last = 0;
            elseif slick(kx,ky) == 0 && last == 0 && is_filling == 1
                solid_im(kx,ky) = 1;
            end
        end
    end
```

1. Image with only shell walls:
   [image: image with only shell walls]
2. Completely filled with `imfill`:
   [image: completely filled with imfill]
3. Image filled by algorithm with bad lines:
   [image: image filled by algorithm with bad lines]
4. Correctly filled image:
   [image: correctly filled image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a an old answer of mine solves the problem:

Refer to: [How can I fill between edges of these characters in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583497/how-can-i-fill-between-edges-of-these-characters-in-matlab/42589016#42589016)

Here is the code:

```
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rdl1.png');
I = imbinarize(rgb2gray(I));

J1 = imfill(I, 'holes');
J2 = imfill(I, [1, 1]);
J3 = imfill(~J2, [1, 1]);
J4 = imfill(~J3, 'holes');
J5 = J1 & (~J4);

figure;imshow(J5)
```

Result:
[image]

I can't guarantee the solution is going to work for thousands of images.